# TWTweetComposeViewController doesn't show link preview

Tags: ios, twitter, ios5

When I add a link to a tweet in the TWTweetComposeViewController, I see the link attached correctly:

[image]

But unlike when I do so in Safari, the link doesn't show a preview of the URL like Safari (or Youtube) does:

[image]

Do you know if it's a hidden feature or if it depends on the Link added to the tweet?

Thank you!

Comment: Hypothetical: If you've already visited the page explicitly (in Safari), then there's no security risk by taking that URL and fetching it for a thumbnail. If you are inserting a link that you've never actually visited, the framework can't safely go fetch the site-- what if the URL is a resource-deleting action?

Comment: That's possible. That would be nice if it was documented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been my experience as well, if you attach a URL the TWTweetComposeViewController will not automatically add a preview image.

I was curious so I took a look at the [private runtime headers for Twitter.framework](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/TWTweetComposeViewController.h) and I found a few interesting methods, including `- (BOOL)addURL:(id)arg1 withPreviewImage:(id)arg2;`. Using this in my app I found it worked exactly as expected, the tweet view showed a link along with the image I included. Unfortunately this doesn't help too much, since it's a private method your app will almost certainly be rejected if you try to use it in the App Store.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Why doesn't Apple just make this method public? So dumb.

Comment: Maybe Apple doesn't want this to be public because the user may think he is sharing an image, but in reality it just adds the URL to the tweet.